# Setting active window on Vim startup

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I'm using MacVim with the [Taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin, which I want to be open all the time when I start MacVim.

So in my .gvimrc I have the following

```
:TlistToggle
```

Which opens the sidebar when I load my MacVim editor. The thing is, when it opens it sets the taglist window to be the 'active' window rather than the new file window directly next to it.

Is there a way of setting the 'active window' at start up? I tried adding this to my rc file

```
:wincmd l
```

Which in theory should move the active window to the right, but this doesn't seem to have any affect.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is freaking annoying that Macvim focuses the first alphabetically ordered tab by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delaying the command until Vim has finished all initializations:

> :autocmd VimEnter * TlistToggle

See:

> :help :autocmd
>   :help VimEnter